# Проблема при установке MySQL Server 8.0

Tags: mysql

Кто-нибудь знает в чем может быть дело?
При установке MySQL Installer Community на этапе конфигурации просит ввести старый пароль root `Current Root Password`. Я не помню вообще ставил ли я когда то сервер, не говоря уж о самом пароле..
Возможно можно как-то сбросить пароль, натыкался на варианты с перезаписью пароля через mysql-init, но там нужно запускать и останавливать сервер, а как мне это сделать если он не установлен до конца и не запускается вообще.

Comment: Если в процессе установки пароль рута не вводился, то старый пароль - пустой.

Comment: у меня требуют ввести пароль Current Root Password, пустым поле я не могу оставить, так как кнопка Next в таком случае остается неактивной

Comment: По идее если не было раньше на сервере mysql, это просьба ввести новый, а не старый (написано же Current - текущий) введите и запишите где-то себе как рут для mysql

Comment: не получается, сколько паролей не ввожу, кнопка Некст остается неактивной, а при нажатии Cheсk появляется крестик красный, как будто неверно введен пароль. На видео по установке этого сервера есть три поля ввода, сам пароль и повторить пароль, у меня же поле одно и чтобы я не вводил все не подходит

Comment: еще на предыдущем шаге пишется у стандартного порта 3306 что он уже используется

Comment: поставил версию сервера поменьше, все заработало....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед переустановкой, нужно удалить папку MYSQL в скрытом каталоге ProgramData. В результате, на этапе конфигурации появляется поле для ввода юзера и пасс - root, root;

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]